# Run the current index again in a foreach-loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is it possible to run the current index again when a certain condition is met in a foreach-loop? Posting a example below.

```
$array = array('this', 'is', 'my', 'array');
$bool = false;
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value.' ';
    if($value == 'my' && !$bool){
        // Rerun the 'my' index again
        $bool = true;
    }
}
```

**Desired output:** this is my my array

Comment: the basic question **WHY**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it *may be* possible (via `prev` or some other hack), the code written this way is hard to understand (even for yourself in a couple of years). For a programmer, the `foreach` construct (at the first glance) looks like a simple iteration over all elements of an array, without jumping back and forth.

Note also that `prev` inside a `foreach` loop *may work in one PHP version but fail in other version*!
[PHP docs say](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the loop **may lead to unexpected behavior**.

I would suggest using a `while` loop in you case (using either indexes or `each`-`prev`-`next` functions).
The `while` construct is immediate signal for a programmer that the iteration logic is more complex than just sequential iteration over array elements.

```
$array = array('this', 'is', 'my', 'array');
$bool = false;

while (list($key, $value) = each($array))  
{
  echo $value.' ';
  if($value == 'my' && !$bool)
  {
    // Rerun the 'my' index again
    $bool = true;
    prev($array);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variant:

```
<?php
$array = array('this', 'is', 'my', 'array');
$bool = false;

foreach ($array as $value) {
    do {
        echo $value.' ';

        if($value == 'my' && !$bool){
            // Rerun the 'my' index again
            $bool = true;
        } else {
            $bool = false;
        }
    } while ($bool);
}
```

Output ([also see here](http://3v4l.org/H2iCY)):

```
this is my my array
```